# Locate template that was used to create cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to locate the template that was used to create/update the stack? All the templates are stored as objects in S3 bucket and created/updated from there. At the moment I can only do that by stack and template name but this is not accurate. I was just wondering does AWS stores this information anywhere.

Comment: The stack has a "Template" tab which contains the template used to create it.

Comment: yes, but it does not show where that template is located. It just shows the content. I need to get the location if it exists.

Comment: That information isn't stored anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This information is stored in CloudTrail, so if you (1) created the stack within the last 90 days, or (2) have CloudTrail configured to store events, you should be able to find it.

Look for the event name `CreateStack`.

Inside the event, `requestParameters.stackName` can be used to filter the events, and and `requestParameters.templateURL` will tell you where the template was stored.

Note that templates which are uploaded from the user's machine are *also* stored in S3, using a CloudFormation-managed bucket in the AWS account.